# How to handle symbolic link in my git repo

Tags: mac, git, symbolic-link, github

I have two git repos, `A` and `B` under separate paths.

There is a sub-folder in one repo (`A/subfolder`) that contains some data files. On my local machine I have a symbolic link in `B` to access these files. This way I do not have to maintain two separate folders with identical contents. It works great.

The problem is that when I push these repos to github, the symbolic links in `B` do not work on other machines (as expected). What is the best way to handle this so that:

- 1) I only have to maintain one physical directory on my local machine;
- 2) Each git repo will contain the physical contents of `subfolder` so that users could clone either repo without issues;
- 3) When I pull from the repo to my local machine, it does not create a duplicate copy of the files in `subfolder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to use hard links instead of symbolic links. Hard links are not natively supported by OS X, but this tool implements them:

https://github.com/selkhateeb/hardlink